# Can I set Mouse Acceleration / Precision mode?

Tags: mouse

Is there a way to set the cursor displacement dependent on mouse velocity? This is called mouse acceleration in most environments. Some call it precision-mode, which is the slow extreme of the speed spectrum.

Behavior Example:

- Move mouse 1 inch at 1 in/s - cursor moves 200 pixels
- Move mouse 1 inch at 2 in/s - cursor moves 500 pixels
- Move mouse 1 inch at 3 in/s - cursor moves 800 pixels

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is some form of acceleration by default.  At least on my system that seems to be the case.

You can use the `xset` command to experiment with this behaviour. For example, `xset m 50 2` sets the *'acceleration'* to **50** and the *'threshold'* to **2**. The cursor will move **50x** times as fast when it travels more than **2** pixels in a short time. For more information see the manual [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xset.1.html).

Comment: There seems to be a point at wich further increasing the acceleration does not actually accelerate the pointer any further. Maybe this depends on trackpad resolution, but on my Macbook, anything above 16 or so does not help anymore.